# Jest change mock after initialize

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to change mock data inside tests after I initialize it.
But when I'm trying to change it, it didn't change... I tried to 'clearAllMocks()' or use jest.spy but nothing changed it.

- when i said changed i mean that ‘ isTablet’ data will change

The initialize that impacts a lot of other tests on the root project.

```
jest-modules-mock.js

jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => ({ isTablet: jest.fn() }));
```

The component

```
Welcome.tsx

const deviceType: BgImageByDevice = isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'mobile';
export default ({ devices }: Welcome): ReactElement => {
const blabla = devices[deviceType]
}
```

The tests

```
Welcome.test.tsx

const devices = {
    tablet: 'tablet',
    mobile: 'mobile',
  },

describe('<Welcome />', () => {

    test('devices should be mobile', () => {
      jest.doMock('react-native-device-info',() => ({  isTablet: () => false }))
      const Welcome = require('./Welcome').default
      const welcomeShallow = shallow(<Welcome devices={devices} />);
      const imageUrl = welcomeShallow.props().source.uri;
      expect(imageUrl).toBe(devices.mobile);
    });

    test('devices should be tablet', () => {
      jest.doMock('react-native-device-info',() => ({  isTablet: () => true }))
      const Welcome = require('./Welcome').default
      const welcomeShallow = shallow(<Welcome devices={devices} />);
      const imageUrl = welcomeShallow.props().source.uri;
      expect(imageUrl).toBe(devices.tablet);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of a mock using a mock file. You can create and export a mock function that you can import in your test and change the implementation or return value. Below is an example of this process.

### `__mocks__\react-native-device-info.js`

```
export const isTablet = jest.fn();
```

### `Welcome.test.js`

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Welcome from "../Welcome";
import { isTablet } from "../__mocks__/react-native-device-info";

const devices = {
  tablet: 'tablet',
  mobile: 'mobile',
};

describe('<Welcome />', () => {
  test('devices should be mobile', () => {
    isTablet.mockReturnValue(false);
    const welcomeShallow = shallow(<Welcome devices={devices} />);
    // Your assertions go here
  });

  test('devices should be tablet', () => {
    isTablet.mockReturnValue(true);
    const welcomeShallow = shallow(<Welcome devices={devices} />);
    // Your assertions go here
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks i'm still getting " Background image › devices should be tablet

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "tablet"
    Received: "mobile""

Comment: Could you add the updated code in your question? I'd also like to see where the source.uri prop is coming from since my code should work given the above example, but I think something was omitted from the Welcome component that would change things.